# Соединить 4 таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно отобразить 4 таблицы mysql  в одной html на php странице?
Например есть 4 таблицы general, class, atribute, dannye. Надо чтобы они всю инфу выводили в 1 общую

Comment: Добавьте схему. INNER JOIN тут поможет.

Comment: Так три (сабж) или четыре (пост)? не, вообще-то пофиг, но просто интересно... `Как можно отобразить 4 таблицы mysql в одной html на php странице?` - написать запрос, который отдаёт информацию из всех таблиц, и именно его использовать как источник данных для вывода.

Comment: например, ровно так же, как и одну, но четыре раза подряд.

Answer (score 1):

используя INNER JOIN но нужно будет указать ключ по которому будет осуществляться соединение таблиц, например 'id', ну или любой другой который будет присутствовать в ваших таблицах

Comment: С этим разобрался, завтра в ответы напишу код. Теперь нужно сделать выборку из этой таблицы, например в general есть машины и когда мы его выбираем то в таблице отображается class, atribute dannye связанные с general

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой получился код с помощью INNER JOIN

```
$zapys=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM global INNER JOIN table_of_class using(id_global) INNER JOIN atribute using(id_class) INNER JOIN dani using(id_atribute)  ") or die(mysql_error());
```